# Public folders security

Tags: windows-permissions

If using one standard user account (for daily task) and one administrator account, then while in standard you can download some virus or whatever and put that into public folder.
of course, assuming the malware is not detected.
Then when admin log's in to it's administrator account, there is a posibility that admin will infect whole system since that malware will be shown in his user profile.

Is there a way to disable public folders or something that can prevent sharing of files between users and administrators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Admin accounts need to be careful about what they run. The rule of thumb is to only run executables that have been vetted, and not to browse the Internet, if at all possible.

Disabling 'Public Folders' is not a solution, but merely a small measure towards the standard practice the Admin should be using.